# Call the callback of another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, callback

If I call function `a()` inside function `b()`, would there be a way to call the callback of function `a()` inside function `b()`?

Here's what I mean in code:

```
function a(callback){
    b()
}

function b() {
    //call the callback() of a()
}
```

Comment: Please provide basic example code demonstrating the constraints of the question.

Comment: Only if you pass it as a parameter, assign to a variable with scope over both functions, or if `b` was created inside `a` and could close over the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have `b` accept a callback parameter as well, and you can pass it through:

```
function a(callback) {
    b(callback)
}

function b(callback) {
    callback();
}
```

There is no other way for `b` to access `a`'s `callback` local variable (parameter), except if `b` is defined within `a` (as a closure).